# Convert from jQuery to Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to transform the following code which is in javascript:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-heartbeat');
});
```

in vue.js.

function name: like

javascript test: https://jsfiddle.net/jsk590ep/

Comment: Please, edit your question to tell the community what you have tried so far. What's your problem on converting this code.

Comment: So I try to convert the code, but it won't. Inside my method: {} I created: like: function () {find ('i'). ToggleClass ('fa-heartbeat')}, but I don't look for the function, and I need an ID in that function called: like

Comment: You can click on the 'Edit' button below your question to add that

Answer (score 4):

In Vue, you typically don't select and manipulate DOM elements directly, you rather bind data to parts of the markup within your Vue components.

That said: You don't even need a function for that.
Simply

- add a data element that indicates which state the icon is in (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering)
- change its value in the `@click` handler of the surrounding `a`, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events
- conditionally bind the `fa` classes based on the state to the icon, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

```
 <a href="#" @click="liked = !liked">
   <i :class="['fa', liked ? 'fa-heartbeat' : 'fa-plus-circle']"></i>
 </a>
```

When looking at the vue docs, note that `@click` in the example is a shortcut for `v-on:click` and `:class` for `v-bind:class`.

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-q-57403395-ul62e?module=/src/App.vue