# Rewrite jQuery Disbale button using javascript in a vue app

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have old jQuery code which I rewriting in javascript for a Vue.js application.

```
function DisableSubmit() {
    submitButton.prop('disabled', true);
    submitButton.attr('data-enabled-value', submitButton.val());
    submitButton.val('WORKING...');
    jQuery(config.formName + ' .spinner-container.fullscreen').show();
  }
```

This is the corresponding html

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style="float: right;"><span><input aria-label="Submit"
                            class="SubmitButton" href="#" id="register"
                            name="Submit" style="color: #fff; padding: 1rem; background-color: #c8102e;" type="submit"
                            value="Submit" /> </span>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <p class="require center" style="color: #fff; margin-left: 1rem;">*Required</p>
                </div>
```

My question is what will be best approach towards this.

Also, I am exactly sure if we have replacements for `.prop()` and `.attr()` in javascript

Comment: Perhaps the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403395/convert-from-jquery-to-vue/57403785#57403785 might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you wouldn't manipulate DOM elements but rather your vue component's state and then bind that state to the DOM.

You'll want to

- bind the button's (data-) attributes to your vue component's state: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes
- bind the button click to a method in your component setting that state: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-q-59026962-onb7j.
I left out the spinner toggle & removed some markup for clarity.