# Get the last div top css in vuejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am converting a jQuery code to vuejs. I have a hard time doing it. I tried to search but I can't find anything clear.

Sample jQuery code is to get the last div top position. The code is like this:

```js
var top = parseInt($(".d1 > .d2> div").last().css("top"));
```

My template code is :

```html
     <template>
        <div class="div1" >
           <div class="div2" ref="busstop">
              <div v-html="renderEl()"></div>
           </div>

           <button @click='test()'>testing</button>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Any Idea on how to convert in to vuejs? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show ur code html ?

Comment: @QuangPhu Hi. Updated my question and included the html template

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert from jQuery to Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403395/convert-from-jquery-to-vue)

Answer (score 3):

in ur case, i will using ref to get lastChildElement div by using [lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild)

First, to get the last child element

```
this.$refs.busstop.lastElementChild
```

and to style for this element

```
this.$refs.busstop.lastElementChild.style.fontSize = "30px";
```

like that

Comment: Damn, never used `lastElementChild`, good one !

Comment: @kissu what about `lastChild`

Comment: neither, usually I use CSS for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so if I understand properly, you want to:

- have a parent w/ a reference
- select the last element of this specific parent
- get it's window's position from the top ?

Here is a demo on how to do this in CSS + Vue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-fog-td190?file=/src/App.vue